# Hello, Im new to flutter and still practicing basics. I wanted to learn how to set default credentials on login page without using firebase auth

Tags: flutter

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
final _username = "admin";
final _password = "123";
final usernameController = TextEditingController();
final passwordController = TextEditingController();


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(body: Container(
      child: Column(children: [
        Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: TextField(
            controller: usernameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(), 
            labelText: "Username"),
            autofocus: true;)),

        Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: TextField(
            controller: passwordController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(), 
            labelText: "Password"),
            obscureText: true;)),
```

how do i compare the values inputted and the default credentials before proceeding to HomePage?

```
    ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: (){Navigator.push(context, 
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));})
        ])
    )
    );
    }
```

What I wanted to happen is once the user entered the correct  default credentials (ex. Uname=admin, pass=123) the login button will proceed to my HomePage(). Else it will give me a message to try it again.  Again, I dont want to use firebase authentication just yet. If there's a way I could do this,

Comment: share your code.

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada hi, thanks for replying immediately, kinda embarassed for my naiveness, but here, I hope you could teach me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

@override
class LoginPageState extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'Home';

  LoginPage createState() => LoginPage();}

class LoginPage extends State<LoginPageState>{
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _username = "admin";
  final _password = "123";
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    usernameController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _submit() {
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      if(_username == usernameController.text && _password == passwordController.text) {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
      } else {
        // whatever you want to do
        // you can show a dialog box
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(children: [
          //USERNAME
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 90.0, 20.0, 20.0),
            child:TextFormField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: usernameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: "Username"),
              validator: (value){
                if (value.isEmpty){
                  return "Username required";}

                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),

          //PASSWORD
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Password"),
                  validator: (value){
                    if (value.isEmpty){
                      return "Password required";}

                    return null;
                  })),

          //LOGIN
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green[300])),
            child: Text("LOGIN",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            onPressed: _submit,
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

it is a good practise to dispose TextEditingController when it is no longer needed. Check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html for more info.

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Will take your advice on my code as well. Really appreciated!

Comment: If you liked the answer, please give it a tick. It will help others and will keep people like me motivated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create two variable username="admin" and password="123".

Get the input from the user and compare with username and password.

If both match simply redirect to the Homepage
Else assign a bool variable like invalid true (Don't forget to use `setState((){})`)
And just above/below the login button create a

```
if(invalid == true)
Text("Try Again")
```

Comment: hello, thanks for replying immediately, will try this on my code! thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, I cant seem to understand this, can you please elaborate this? Or perhaps show me a code regarding this? Thank you!

"If both match simply redirect to the Homepage Else assign a bool variable like invalid true (Don't forget to use setState((){})) And just above/below the login button create a

if(invalid == true)
Text("Try Again") "

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, I finally got this. Thanks to @adrsh23 for the answer! So here's how I did it:

First I have the scaffolded login page. This does not contain my login form just yet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'LoginPageState.dart';



class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget{
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 90.0, 20.0, 20.0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green[300],
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 20.0),
                child: Text("Sample Flutter Login"))),
            
             LoginPageState(),]
        )
      )
    )

  );
}
}
```

And here, I created a stateful widget that already contains my form:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

@override
class LoginPageState extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage createState() => LoginPage();}

class LoginPage extends State<LoginPageState>{
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _username = "admin";
  final _password = "123";
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(children: [
        //USERNAME
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 90.0, 20.0, 20.0),
            child:TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            controller: usernameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(), 
            labelText: "Username"),
            validator: (value){
                if (value.isEmpty  || value != _username){
              return "Input correct username";}

            return null;
            })),

        //PASSWORD
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: TextFormField(
            obscureText: true,
            controller: passwordController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(), 
            labelText: "Password"),
            validator: (value){
                if (value.isEmpty || value != _password){
              return "Input correct password";}

            return null;
            })),

        //LOGIN
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green[300])),
            child: Text("LOGIN",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          onPressed: ( ) {
            if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
              Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            }
          },
            )
          ]
         )
        ); 
  
  }


}
```

I used this for a basic flutter login that does not have firebase auth, instead using a default credentials.

Comment: Looks good! For more details about set state [click here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html). Actually I was saying by using set state you can show a error message that username/password is wrong in the UI just above or below the Login button. But your option is also correct and easy.

Comment: Thank you again, really appreciated your help!